# Как поиск по категории прижать к footer'у?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LEO IMAGES</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="category">
            <h1 id="browse">BROWSE BY CATEGORY</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Abstract</td>
                        <td>Business/Finance</td>
                        <td>Holidays</td>
                        <td>Nature</td>
                        <td>Signs/Symbols</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Animals/Wildlife</td>
                        <td>Celebrities</td>
                        <td>Illustrations/Clip-Art</td>
                        <td>Objects</td>
                        <td>Sports/Recreation</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>The Arts</td>
                        <td>Editorial</td>
                        <td>Industrial</td>
                        <td>Parks/Outdoor</td>
                        <td>Technology</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bacgrounds/Textures</td>
                        <td>Education</td>
                        <td>Interiors</td>
                        <td>People</td>
                        <td>Transportation</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Beauty/Fashion</td>
                        <td>Food and Drink</td>
                        <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                        <td>Religion</td>
                        <td>Vectors</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Buildings/Landmarks</td>
                        <td>Healthcare/Medical</td>
                        <td>Model Released Only</td>
                        <td>Science</td>
                        <td>Vintage</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>

<footer>
        <p class="footer">Copyrigth &copy 2013 Css Author</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

    body {
    background: white;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Segoe wp light", sans-serif ;
}

#browse {
    color: #7e7e7e;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table {
    color: #b9b9b9;
    line-height: 20px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #484242;
    color: #959292;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

p.footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Вот что получается.]

[image: Вот что должно быть.]